# Почему FormData пустая? Как передать фото с помощью ajax POST запроса?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

Есть форма `Django`, которая отрисовывает следующий шаблон. Нужно с помощью `ajax Post запроса` передать эти файлы в определённую функцию. Как я понял, это нужно реализовывать через `FormData()`, но беда в том, что никак не удаётся с ней разобраться - внутри объекта ничего нет..

```
  <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="9S6oPbkHujBnxaKHSxzU5W4mdkEs6Lbbf3g0OIJAk3lBfaMV8bafzpz8QudIuofJ">
  9S6oPbkHujBnxaKHSxzU5W4mdkEs6Lbbf3g0OIJAk3lBfaMV8bafzpz8QudIuofJ
    <div class="field inline">
        <div class="subhead">Фото главной страницы паспорта:</div>

        <input type="file" name="main_photo" required="" id="id_main_photo">
        <label for="foto1" class="id_foto">
            <div class="addPhoto">
                <div class="button"></div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="field inline">
        <div class="subhead">Фото в профиль с раскрытым паспортом в руке:</div>
        <input type="file" name="profile_photo" required="" id="id_profile_photo">
        <label for="foto2" class="id_foto">
            <div class="addPhoto">
                <div class="button"></div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
      <button class="submit mgln" type="button">Послать запрос</button>
    </div>
```

Скрипт

```
$('.mgln').on('click', function(){
  var photo = new FormData();
  console.log(photo)
  photo.append('file1', $('input[name=main_photo]').val()) 
  photo.append('file2', $('input[name=profile_photo]').val())
  console.log(photo)
data = {
    photo: photo,
  }
})
```

пробовал вытаскивать файлы через `files[0]` (выпадала ошибка). Пробовал передавать в FormData саму форму через `get(0)` (формдата была пустой)... Видимо, я что-то не так делал..
Вот [доки](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

**upd.**

```
photo = new FormData();
photo.append('file1', $('input[name=main_photo]').prop('files')[0])
console.log(photo)
```

в ответ приходит пустая `FormData`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И в таком варианте тоже

```
var photo = new FormData($(this).closest("form")[0]);
console.log(photo)
```

Comment: 2 раза `'file1'` это в любом случае не правильно

Comment: этот код ничего не делает

Comment: таки да, ничего не делает, только составляет объект

Comment: @Igor, как быть, подскажите?(

Comment: Пробовал, кстати, через `GET` передавать. Прилетал `fake path`

Comment: `console.log(photo)` - это ни о чем не говорит

Comment: @Igor ого... не знал об этом... а как проверить тогда-то?)

Comment: `FormData.keys()`, `FormData.get()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form ... enctype="multipart/form-data">

var photo = new FormData($(this).closest("form")[0]);
```

Comment: всё-равно пустая.

Comment: обновил код....

Comment: это есть `<form action="" class="edit_form new_event" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">`

Comment: "всё-равно пустая." - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: `console.log()`. больше не знаю, как проверить. Если только передавать аяксом и уже в функции самой смотреть на стороне джанго.

Answer (score 1):

в [доке](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) написано

```
formData.append('userpic', myFileInput.files[0], 'chris.jpg');
```

соответственно Вам надо написать как-то так

```
photo.append('file1', $('input[name=main_photo]').prop('files')[0])
```

Comment: обновил код....